# Inequality in H-curl function space

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, lp-spaces, nonlinear-system

Define a function space V ,
$$
V:=\{\mathbf{v} \in \mathbf{L}^{1+\alpha}(\Omega), \mathbf{curl}~\mathbf{v} \in \mathbf{L}^2(\Omega)\},
$$
equipped with graph norm
$$
\|\mathbf{v}\|_{V} := \|\mathbf{v}\|_{\mathbf{L}^{1+\alpha}(\Omega)} + \|\mathbf{curl~v}\|_{\mathbf{L}^2(\Omega)},
$$
where, the real number $0<\alpha\le 1$, and $\Omega$ is a bounded domain.

Clearly, when $\alpha = 1$, V becomes to be $\mathbf{H}(\mathbf{curl},\Omega)$. As we all know,
$$
\|\mathbf{v}\|_{\mathbf{H}(\mathbf{curl},\Omega)} \le C \big(\|\mathbf{curl}~\mathbf{v}\|_{\mathbf{L}^2(\Omega)} +\|div~\mathbf{v}\|_{L^2(\Omega)}\big),
$$
for any $\mathbf{v} \in \mathbf{H}(\mathbf{curl},\Omega)$.

Do functions in V with $0<\alpha<1$ have the similar result, i.e., 
$$
\|\mathbf{v}\|_{V} \le C \big(\|\mathbf{curl}~\mathbf{v}\|_{\mathbf{L}^2(\Omega)} +\|div~\mathbf{v}\|_{L^2(\Omega)}\big)
$$
for any function $\mathbf{v}\in V$?